# How to list all (groovy) classes in JVM in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jvm, classpath

I am writing a DelegatingMetaClass that I would like to apply to all groovy classes in my project, but I do not how to get hold of all classes in the project?

Here is the code:

```
 /*
 This will work ok, since I know Foo beforehand, but what about classes 
 that do not exist yet?
 */
 def myMetaClass = new DelegatingMetaClass(Foo.class)
 InvokerHelper.metaRegistry.setMetaClass(Foo.class, myMetaClass)    

 /*
 how to do this?
 allGroovyClasses.each{
      def myMetaClass = new DelegatingMetaClass(it)
      InvokerHelper.metaRegistry.setMetaClass(it, myMetaClass)  
         }
 */


 class SimpleInterceptor extends DelegatingMetaClass{


 public SimpleInterceptor(final Class aclass) {
   super(aclass);    
   initialize();
 }

 public Object getProperty(Object object, String prop) {
     println ("I am in a property interceptor!!!")
   return super.getProperty(object, prop)
 }

 public Object invokeMethod(Object a_object, String a_methodName, Object[] a_arguments)
 {
     println ("I am in a method interceptor!!!")
     return super.invokeMethod(a_object, a_methodName, a_arguments) 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an [example of how to do this in java](http://dzone.com/snippets/get-all-classes-within-package), which should also work with groovy. I think it's a sketchy way to do it though.

- Do you need to intercept getters/setters in domain classes? [Hibernate has support for that](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) (I assume GORM too).
- Do you need to intercept controller actions? You can use [controller interceptors](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Interceptors).

What's you goal?

Comment: I'm trying to use interception for AOP style programming.